# react native draggable flatlist throwing error on drag release

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[Rendering Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjwYk.png)I have specific imageplaceholders of 6. I can drag the image but on release it's showing me error => Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method.

I am working on draggable flatlist where I have specific imageplaceholders of 6. I can drag the image but on release it's showing me error => Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method.[DraggableFlatlist props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmlpv.png)

**strong text**